# HQL Related issue unexpected token: InnerJoin near line 1, column 257

Tags: hibernate

```
select a.fmId, a.nameFirstMarketing, a.nameLastMarketing, a.lotusNotesEmailAddress
from Advisor a
where a.fmId in
    (Select ae.id.fmId
    from AdvsEnrl ae
    where ae.enrlProcCmplTstp IS NOT NULL
    InnerJoin
    select aor.id.identifierDisplayNumber 
    from AdvsOboRel aor
    where aor.id.identifierDisplayNumber in
        (select ae.id.fmId
        from AdvsEnrl ae where ae.enrlProcCmplTstp IS NOT NULL;
```

I got this error can u please tell how to resolve that one
unexpected token: InnerJoin near line 1, column 257

Comment: InnerJoin doesn't exists. Parenthesis are not balanced. This query doesn't work in SQL too

Comment: How to write this query joe

Comment: Dear, post your table structure and your function goal

Comment: in advisor table fmid and name firstmarketing and namelastmarketing and lotusnotesemail address columns and advsenrl table also fmid and but we should enrlproccmpltstp is not null and third table Displaynumber means here fmid in advsoborel table we can use inner join replace union

Comment: Please if possible edit your question. Post structure table as follow: Table name and then columns.

Comment: table name advisor columns fmid, nameFirstMarketing,nameLastMarketing,lotusNotesEmailAddresss. second table advsenrl columns enrlProcCmplTstp ,fmid third table advsobo rel column identifierDisplayNumber  once advisor enrolled advisor details added second table

Comment: AdvsEnrl and AdvsOboRel how relationed?

Comment: advsenrl fmid and advsobo rel identifierDisplayNumber same

Comment: advsOboRel has a fk to AdvsEnrl in POJO?

Comment: advsOboRel has a fk to AdvsEnrl in POJO yes right joe

Comment: Have you resolved with my indications?

Comment: Ok, I'm happy for you. If you want, because you are newbie, if answer accomplish your request, please accept clicking on tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comments written between us:

Try this:

```
select
    a.fmId, a.nameFirstMarketing, a.nameLastMarketing,
    a.lotusNotesEmailAddress
from Advisor a
where a.fmId in
    (Select aor.identifierDisplayNumber
    from AdvsOboRel aor
    where aor.identifierDisplayNumber in 
        (select ae.fmId
        from AdvsEnrl ae where ae.enrlProcCmplTstp IS NOT NULL)
    )
```

If `AdvsOboRel` class has a property (many-to-one) refer to `AdvsEnrl` you can remove the last IN clause, using a dot notation to get info about `AdvsEnrl`